# Early plot question - intro video and a battlefield - minor spoilers

Tags: the-witcher-3

Last warning, there are minor early plot spoilers in this question.

So, in the opening video, Yennefer finds herself in the middle of a battlefield and drops some stone that causes a big explosion and wrecks soldiers and messes up the ground.

Is this the same battlefield that's outside White Orchard, i.e. the one you go to for the Missing in Action side quest?

Comment: Unless one of the developers answers, there is no way to confirm this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is the same battlefield.

At start of the game, after the dream of Kear Morhen, you fight some Ghouls with Vesemir.
If you look around after the fight you can find the crystal bird skull on the ground.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I guess I was expecting a bigger battlefield for the two armies to charge at each other. Also wondered if there would be any evidence of the explosion she caused. Then again, FMV sequences aren't directed by the level designers. If you can find anymore evidence, I'll mark it as an answer. Cheers